# NextJS, framer-motion: How do I make an animation fire only on initial page load and reset every 12 hours?

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, local-storage, framer-motion

I have a website with a main page that loads in with a framer-motion animation. How do I make it so that the animation fires only on initial page load and not whenever I refresh the page/switch from one page back to the main page? I'm using NextJS so local storage is only available after the first render inside a useEffect() hook. Is there a way I can call a callback after a motion.div animation fires? I'm thinking of setting local storage after the animation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.framer.com/docs/component/#props), you could disable the animation (stop firing) by setting the value of `initial` props to `false` instead of your current `animation properties` (Same for the `animate` prop).

> Set to false to initialise with the values in animate (disabling the mount animation).

Perhaps to achieve what you want, you could simply use a useState to solve:

```js
const [runAnimation,setRunAnimation] = React.useState(false)

React.useEffect(()=>{
    /* Some logic to know whether the user has run animation before */

    const needToRunAnimation = ...

    if (needToRunAnimation){
        setRunAnimation(yourAnimationProperty)
    }
},[])
```

Then you could apply the `runAnimation` property to the framer motion component, to control whether the animation will fire.